# Solicitudes entre aplicaciones c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

***Hola, Busco conectar una aplicación de windows form C# y otra de xamarin android. ¿como puedo hacer para que mi aplicacion xamarin envié una solicitud/notificación a la aplicación form y esta misma le responda?
Les agradecería si me hicieran saber un código, ejemplo, algo similar, tema o algo así.***

Comment: si tienes de intermdiario servicio webapi, podrias comunicarlos por medio de estos. Si quieres algo mas realtime lo haces con SignalR